# is there a way remove all childnode <br> inside document

Tags: javascript, html

I found a code example online, about how to convert HTML table into CSV. The code seems fine.
https://jsfiddle.net/3p0r2haq/12/

```
function download_csv(csv, filename) {
    var csvFile;
    var downloadLink;

    // CSV FILE
    csvFile = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/csv"});

    // Download link
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    // File name
    downloadLink.download = filename;

    // We have to create a link to the file
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);

    // Make sure that the link is not displayed
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";

    // Add the link to your DOM
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    // Lanzamos
    downloadLink.click();
}

function export_table_to_csv(html, filename) {
    var csv = [];
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th ");
        
        for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) 
                
            row.push(cols[j].innerText);
        
        csv.push(row.join(","));        
    }

    // Download CSV
    download_csv(csv.join("\n"), filename);
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var html = document.querySelector("table").outerHTML;
    export_table_to_csv(html, "table.csv");
});
```

However, the  document has node `<br>`, which will mass up str. I added an example here. My question is how to avoid the `<br>` node or remove them all before query?

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Geronimo</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td><br>France</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Natalia</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>Spain</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Silvia</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>Russia</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

So the result will mass up like the image [image]

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('br').forEach(el => el.remove())`?

Answer (score 2):

Just change

```
row.push(cols[j].innerText);
```

To

```
row.push(cols[j].innerText.trim());
```

Using `trim()` will remove the `\n` and any other whitespace in a cell

```js
function export_table_to_csv(html, filename) {
    var csv = [];
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th ");
        
        for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) 
                
            row.push(cols[j].innerText.trim());
        
        csv.push(row.join(","));        
    }
     // Download CSV
     // download_csv(csv.join("\n"), filename);
    
    // log results for demo instead of download
    console.log(csv)
   
}
export_table_to_csv()
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Geronimo</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td><br>France</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Natalia</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>Spain</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Silvia</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>Russia</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Feel free to accept answer if it helped you solve your issue